# How can i change view to a JTree?

Tags: java, jtree

it's possible, and how, to change a view to a jTree ? i would like this http://ksprog.net/fig52.JPG

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An example on how to implement a [custom tree renderer](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/CreatingaCustomRenderer.htm) shows that you're probably better off to draw the tree yourself, unless you benefit from other features of Jtree (considering your example).